# Can Bridge To Kubernetes support HTTPS for local service?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using Bridge To Kubernets to develop a Asp.Net Core API application locally.

The service uses Swagger that has a Login button to get OAuth2 token. The OAuth flow requires HTTPS protocl.

When running the service locally with Bridge to Kubernetes, I noticed that the service only listens on HTTP not HTTPS.

Searched [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/overview-bridge-to-kubernetes) on Microsoft but no mentions of HTTPS.
Searched [source code](https://github.com/Azure/Bridge-To-Kubernetes/blob/ac992a7c15da94eb541d54f76598307043e8ad8d/src/library/Connect/WorkloadInformationProvider.cs) in GitHub and seems Bridge To Kubernetes only supports HTTP.

Just want to see if there is a workaround or it does not support HTTPS at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out a way to do it by overwriting an environment variable URLS.

In the *KubernetesLocalProcessConfig.yaml* file,

```
  - name: URLS
    value: https://localhost:5001
```

This will make local service listening on HTTPS and port 5001.

The code helps me to see all the environment variables,

```
foreach (var c in builder.Configuration.AsEnumerable())
{
   Console.WriteLine(c.Key + " = " + c.Value);
}
```